# Module in Python

Tags: python

Command :Import setuptools .

Where python will going to search the setuptools ?

Like command : Import ryu.hooks

In this case it will search the ryu folder then import the code into the script which is calling it .

-Ajay

Comment: Which part of the tutorial did you have trouble with?

Answer (score 3):

> the interpreter first searches for a built-in module

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path